# Bootstrap carousel not working locally, but works with online link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I am working on a website for a school project and am using bootstrap. I downloaded bootstrap js e css files so I could use locally, so even if I don't have internet connection bootstrap would still work.

Everything was working fine, no problem with bootstrap, until I used a carousel.For some reason, my carousel wouldn't work, only the first image would appear. It didn't matter what i changed, nothing would work.

Then I tried changing the bootstrap files to the online links on the bootstrap website, and to my surprise, the carousel started working!

So why does the carousel only work with online bootstrap link and not local bootstrap files?

Below are the bootstrap files, locally and the web link. I am not providing the carousel html code because that is not the problem, seeing as i took it from the bootstrap website, and it is working, just not locally.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->

<!-- Boostrap Minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Plugin jQuery -->
<!--<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If anyone has had the same problem and nows how to solve it, i would apreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried importing everything locally on the same order? (Bootstrap's CSS => jQuery => Bootstrap's Js)... If you did, then maybe the issue is the version of the files you are using

Comment: Yes, i used the recommended order on the bootstrap order. I also am using the version from the online link, so both the online and local versions should be the same? I got everything from the official bootstrap website, so I'm guessing it's the latest versions

Comment: Do you get any errors on console when you try using the carousel?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your calls failed because you did not call bootstrap.bundle.min.js (w/ Popper.js). You called the unbundled version (bootstrap.min.js) which does not include popper.js.

This is discussed in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#css-files